# Use Firebase Cloud Functions to move large list in the Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to move a list of 2000+ objects in a list to new location in my Realtime Database? I would let Firebase Cloud Functions handle this move but do not want to put the 2000+ objects into memory before I move them. I have noticed that a timeout can happen for larger list. Is there a faster more efficient way to handle all this?

Comment: Do you want to do that only once or regularly?

Comment: Looking to do it more regularly

Answer (score 1):

Realtime Database doesn't have a "move" operation.  You will have to read them into memory, write them to the new location, then delete the originals.  You don't have to read the entire thing into memory - you could instead page through them using range queries.

Answer (score 0):

After working with the Realtime Database for a little while I found [this example](https://gist.github.com/jofftiquez/f60dc81b39d77cd4eb1f5b5cbe6585ad) to be the best answer. Also if the list if rather large I found adding the code below helps with load and timeout. [Here is more about it.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation)

```
.runWith({ memory: '2GB', timeoutSeconds: 120 })
```